# Can we check programmatically if iOS device has low memory situation?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a situation where lots of transactions have to uploaded to the server. I have made this job asynchronously using `NSManagedObjectContext` `performBlock:` method that performs block on the `NSManagedObjectContext` queue. So in the async-block how can I observe the low memory warning! Instead of observing I would like to determine if the device has enough free memory then only upload data. Otherwise if it has low-memory situation then wait till low-memory happens and then resume the upload job.

Answer (score 0):

You can check free disk space of your iOS device before upload data to avoid low-memory situation.

```
+(uint64_t)getFreeDiskspace {

    uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];

    if (dictionary) {
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %ld", [error domain], (long)[error code]);
    }
    return totalFreeSpace;
}
```